# remotemysql.com cannot connect with python neither on the site manually

Tags: python, mysql, remote-mysql

I try to reach to my remotemysql database with my Python script which worked fine first, now it doesn't connect anymore so I went to remotemysql.com/login.php but it gives an error

> `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

anyone know if its only for me or if remotemysql.com is having problems?
my code for Python should also be fine.
these are random credentials in my code btw.

````
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
      host='remotemysql.com',
      database='thydfc2',
      user='thydfc2',
      password=os.environ.get('databasepass'))

  except Error as e:
    print(e)
  if conn.is_connected():
      mycursor = conn.cursor()```
````

Comment: Did you just expose your database credentials?

Comment: Btw, the error message does not make sense for a remote mysql database as it indicates that you are trying to connect through sockets file. Sockets file can only be used for localhost access, not for remote.

Comment: i am not exposing my password, and i am trying to login on the website without any code then i get that error code, with python i just get error connection failed